# SQL - How to find entries where a value is missing between two rows

Tags: sql, presto

We are using Presto SQL at my job. I have spent hours trying to search for the answer to this question but can't find an answer and it's quite difficult to search for. Solving this issue opens the door to fixing a lot of problems.

I need to write a query that tries to find all entries where REQUEST_CANCEL & CHARGED exist but CANCEL_ACCOUNT is missing.

CHARGED & CANCEL_ACCOUNT should always come after REQUEST_CANCEL.

Table Name: CUSTOMER_INFO

```
|DATE_TIME|CUST_ID |ACTION        |
|20180726 |1234    |CHARGED       |
|20180726 |1234    |CANCEL_ACCOUNT|
|20180726 |1234    |REQUEST_CANCEL|
```

All these values exist in the same table. Here's what I have so far.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT *
    FROM CUSTOMER_INFO
        WHERE 
        DATE_TIME = 20180726
        AND ACTION = REQUEST_CANCEL) as a
JOIN
    (SELECT *
    FROM CUSTOMER_INFO
    WHERE
    DATE_TIME = 20180726
    AND ACTION = CHARGED) as b
ON a.CUST_ID = b.CUST_ID
WHERE 
    a.TIME < b.TIME
```

Let me explain it in a way that makes sense.

```
A = REQUEST_CANCEL
B = CANCEL_ACCOUNT
C = CHARGED
```

How do you query for when A and C exist but B is missing. The sequence needs to be exact A > B > C. It's essentially querying for something that doesn't exist between two values that do exist. In my current query, B can be returned between the two values and that's NOT what I want.

Comment: Can you set up a [fiddle](https://www.sqlfiddle.com)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're searching for `NOT EXISTS` and a corellated subquery.

```
SELECT *
       FROM (SELECT *
                    FROM customer_info
                    WHERE action = 'REQUEST_CANCEL') rc
            INNER JOIN (SELECT *
                               FROM customer_info
                               WHERE action = 'CHARGED') c
                       ON c.cust_id = rc.cust_id
                          AND c.date_time >= rc.date_time
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM customer_info ca
                                WHERE ca.cust_id = rc.cust_id
                                      AND ca.action = 'CANCEL_ACCOUNT'
                                      AND ca.date_time >= rc.date_time
                                      AND ca.date_time <= c.date_time);
```

Comment: You are a total wizard sticky bit. Thanks so much for the help!!!

There are so many applications for this and my coworkers were jokingly saying if we could pay you we would :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` and `having`:

```
select cust_id
from customer_info ci
where date_time = 20180726 and
      action in ('REQUEST_CANCEL', 'CHARGED', 'CANCEL_ACCOUNT')
group by cust_id
having sum(case when action = 'REQUEST_CANCEL' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when action = 'CHARGED' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when action = 'CANCEL_ACCOUNT' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 ;
```

Each `sum()` counts the number of matching records for the customer with that action.  The `> 0` says that one exists.  The `= 0` says that none exist.

The database doesn't matter for this logic.  [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6318a2/1) is a SQL Fiddle using MySQL.

Comment: Strange. I wrote it this way and no results were returned. Using the HAVING clause, can I expect to see additional columns with the value 1 next to the cust_id? Or does it just return cust_id if "REQUEST_CANCEL' and 'CHARGED" are true.

Comment: @Richard . . . If you want additional columns, you need to move the expressions into the `select`.  The code works as shown in the SQL Fiddle I just added.